# x commits behind master, how to do without merge master on branch

Tags: git

I'm working with git to maintain mine code nad now I have basically 3 branches:

- master (protected, not possible to edit directelly)
- develop
- releaseversion (can be v1, v2 etc..)

a long time ago I had a accedentally merge on master which I reverted by interface (on master branch only), but now I have the develop branch always 10 commits behind master, but I can't do the merge of master into develop because it will cause code regression.

How can I reset these commits behind on develop? is there a way to "cancel" these commits on master? Or a way to reset master based on current status of develop?

Thank you

Comment: I would recommend using tags for release versions, not branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be bigger issues here (in that you have a reverted merge, which will get in the way if ever in the future you want to re-merge those commits' changes into `master`).

That said, the *simplest* way to keep git from saying that you're behind `master` without affecting the contents of the `develop` branch is to merge using the `ours` merge strategy (which is *not* to be confused with the `ours` option that can be given to the default merge strategy).

```
git checkout develop
git merge -s ours master
```

On paper, this tells git that `develop` isn't *really* behind `master`, that `master` just contains commits that will never be relevant to `develop`.

The downside to this is that it "hides" changes in the merge.  Some commands (and possibly some developers) assume that if a merge commit's parents could've been merged without conflict using the default merge strategy, then that's what happened - and so merges, like this one, that break that assumption are sometimes called "evil merges".

Another option is to go ahead and merge `master` into `develop` normally, but then revert *that* merge.

```
git checkout develop
git merge master
git revert -m1 HEAD
```

I know that sounds like it makes the first concern I raised even worse, but this is the rare case where two wrongs may make a right.  The advantage here is that (roughly speaking) in some future merge that combines the `develop` history with `master` again, git will see the revert on `develop` (the re-instatement of the changes) as happening *after* the revert on `master` - so the merge would behave like you'd expect.  And you don't have any "evil" (or otherwise weird) merges.

Comment: The only thing I would add (if this is what you mean) is that having merged master into develop the idea is to turn around and merge develop into master immediately. The reverse merge is merely to advance the LCA, as I understand it.

Comment: @matt No, there is no reason for an immediate re-mege to master. The whole poitn is that OP just *reverted* the merge to master because they don't want the changes there (at least yet); why would you suggest they undo that?

Comment: I thought the goal _was_ to merge develop into master but not to see the "10 commits behind" any more. I could just be confused.